# Displaying different ObservableList in a single TableView [JavaFX]

Tags: java, javafx

I have a layout which basically consists of `ChoiceBox` and `TableView`. What I'd like to achieve is to display different data in `TableView` basing on the selected option in `ChoiceBox`.

What I have so far is:

**MainController** class:

```
private void configureChoiceBox() {
        choiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener((v, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if(newValue.intValue() == 0) {
                workshopList.setItems(data.getPipeCableList());
            }
            else if(newValue.intValue() == 1) {
                workshopList.setItems(data.getElementList());
            }
        });
    }
```

**Data** class:

```
    private ObservableList<PipeCable> pipeCableList;
    private ObservableList<Element> elementList;
    /**/
    private ObservableList<StoredItem> displayedList;

    public Data() {
        this.pipeCableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        this.elementList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        /**/
        this.displayedList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    }

    public ObservableList<StoredItem> getPipeCableList() {
    displayedList.removeAll(elementList);   
    displayedList.addAll(pipeCableList);
        return displayedList;
    }

    public ObservableList<StoredItem> getElementList() {
    displayedList.removeAll(pipeCableList); 
    displayedList.addAll(elementList);
        return displayedList;
    }
```

**The problem is:** when I change between options in `ChoiceBox` the data from both `elementList` and `pipeCableList` are mixed together and changing option in `ChoiceBox` has no result whatsoever.

**What I'd like to achieve:** be able to display different data which is contained in `elementList` and `pipeCableList` according to option selected with `ChoiceBox`. What's more, when one option is selected (one list is displayed) all new items which are added to this list will be visible on `TableView`.

**EDIT(added missing info):** `PipeCable` and `Element` extends `StoredItem` and `TableView` takes items of type `StoredItem`.

Comment: Do any of the StoredItem, PipeCable and Element classes define their own `equals(Object)` methods?

Comment: No, they do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What's going wrong*

Get rid of displayList, the TableView already has a reference to the list of items it displays, so just set that to the appropriate list.  Currently your display list values are getting out of synch with your underlying data values.

*Assumptions*

I assume your TableView takes items of type StoredItem and both PipeCable and Element are also of type StoredItem (though inheritance or interface implementation).

*How to fix it*

Usually, you could just do:

```
tableView.setItems(data.getPipeCableList())
```

and the same for the element list as appropriate when it is chosen.  But due to some limitations of Java generics that I can't seem to easily get around, that does not compile.  If both the element list and pipe cable list were the same types (rather than children of a common parent type), it would be no issue.

To get around the generics issue, you can do:

```
tableView.getItems().setAll(data.getPipeCableList())
```

Which works fine, but does not keep the table view items in synch with the data items if the data items change.

To keep these in synch, you can do:

```
Bindings.bindContent(tableView.getItems(), data.getPipeCableList());
```

which is a bit ugly, but appears to work.

*Full Sample App*

[image: sample]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class MultiListTable extends Application {
    enum ItemType {
        PipeCable, Element
    }

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        TableView<StoredItem> tableView = new TableView<>();

        TableColumn<StoredItem, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        nameColumn.setPrefWidth(120);

        tableView.getColumns().add(nameColumn);

        Data data = new Data();

        ChoiceBox<ItemType> choiceBox = new ChoiceBox<>(
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(ItemType.values())
        );

        choiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            switch (newValue) {
                case PipeCable:
                    Bindings.bindContent(tableView.getItems(), data.getPipeCableList());
                    break;

                case Element:
                    Bindings.bindContent(tableView.getItems(), data.getElementList());
                    break;
            }
        });

        choiceBox.getSelectionModel().select(0);

        Button addPipe = new Button("Add Pipe");
        addPipe.setOnAction(event -> data.getPipeCableList().add(
                new PipeCable("Pipe " + (data.getPipeCableList().size() + 1))
        ));
        IntStream.range(0, 3).forEach(i -> addPipe.fire());

        Button addElement = new Button("Add Element");
        addElement.setOnAction(event -> data.getElementList().add(
                new Element("Element " + (data.getElementList().size() + 1))
        ));
        IntStream.range(0, 2).forEach(i -> addElement.fire());

        HBox controls = new HBox(10, choiceBox, addPipe, addElement);

        VBox layout = new VBox(10, controls, tableView);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    class Data {
        private ObservableList<PipeCable> pipeCableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        private ObservableList<Element> elementList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        ObservableList<PipeCable> getPipeCableList() {
            return pipeCableList;
        }

        ObservableList<Element> getElementList() {
            return elementList;
        }
    }

    static public class StoredItem {
        private final ReadOnlyStringWrapper name;

        public StoredItem(String name) {
            this.name = new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(name);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name.get();
        }

        public ReadOnlyStringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name.getReadOnlyProperty();
        }
    }

    static public class PipeCable extends StoredItem {
        public PipeCable(String name) {
            super(name);
        }
    }

    static public class Element extends StoredItem {
        public Element(String name) {
            super(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. The problem with your solution is the generics and inheritance. At line `return pipeCableList` IDE displays error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from ObservableList<PipeCable> to ObservableList<StoredItem>.
The same applies to `return elementList`. That's why I used `displayedList` in `Data` class - simply to do something equivalent to casting (?)

Comment: @MariuszMikołajczak Change the declarations of `pipeCableList` and `elementList` to be `ObservableList<StoredItem>`. Alternatively, change the return types of the methods to be `ObservableList<PipeCable>` and `ObservableList<Element>`, respectively, and change the code that populates the table (presumably a `TableView<StoredItem>`) to be `tableView.getItems().setAll(data.getPipeCableList());`, etc.

Comment: @James_D now it works. I must have somehow missed this when I was trying to figure it out on my own. Thank you both very much.

Comment: Updated answer as per James suggestion.

Comment: @James_D There is still one thing missing with getItems() method in comparison with setItems(). The first method do not refresh the view when a new item is added. I tried to use `tableView.refresh()` method after `addItem` action but still it doesn't.

Comment: @MariuszMikołajczak That is correct. `tableView.getItems().setAll(...)` copies the elements from the specified list to the table's list, so if you are manipulating the lists returned by `data.getXXXList()` after calling `table.getItems().setAll(..)` those changes will not be reflected in the list. You can do `Bindings.bindContent(table.getItems(), data.getXXXList());` instead of `table.getItems().setAll(...);`.